# Amplify mock changes are now permanent after push

Tags: api, mocking, aws-amplify

I am experiencing a major problem with my Vue app using Amplify!

I ran *amplify mock api* which included:

```
"aws_appsync_dangerously_connect_to_http_endpoint_for_testing": true
```

in my aws-export.js file. I failed to stop the mock server (which would have removed the above line from the aws-exports.js file) and ran **amplify push**. I am now unable to remove this line.

Since then I am experiencing issues when running the app, for example web-socket time outs and  intermittent syncing of the DataStore data.

How can I reverse these changes made by running amplify mock and which are now permanently in the backend?